# Read file from FTP in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am loading request file to FTP (below flow where loading part works perfectly fine).

I am trying to read file (which is result of request file load) from FTP server and could not find any solution. Any suggestion?

```
<flow name="FTP_FLOW">
                <file:inbound-endpoint responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" path="D:\AnypointStudio\workspace\ftppoc\src\test\resources\in" pollingFrequency="10000" moveToDirectory="D:\AnypointStudio\workspace\ftppoc\src\test\resources\backup"/>
                <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="hostname" port="21" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP" password="password" path="/path" user="username"/>

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ftp connector provided by MuleSoft can write a file from within a flow or it can poll a directory (inbound connector).

When you want to read a file with given name within a flow, you can use the open source connector from here: https://github.com/rbutenuth/ftp-client-connector/